# Send Headers from NodeJS to Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http-headers

I have a Node server running a single-page Angular web app.  The requests to my server come in from a reverse proxy that attaches a set of headers for authentication. On certain events, the Angular app sends requests to another server, and those requests need to have the same authentication headerset that the Node server received from the reverse proxy. Is there a mechanism by which I can send the headers from Node to the client-side Javascript so that I can then pass them through in the requests made by my Angular web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ExpressJS for NodeJs. There's a headers object present into request and response objects you can read/write. You can send it to client through a parameter (maybe) It depends what your client receive.

Example in coffee

```
# JSON response width previously req.headers
app.get /hello, (req, res) ->
  res.json { status: 'OK', data: { headers: req.headers }

# Or you can use setHeader to set a special param in header
app.get /hello, (req, res) ->
  res.setHeaders "foo", "bar"
  res.json { status: 'OK' }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was able to find an alternative solution based on some services provided by my company, but accepting this answer for completeness.